# Movie about a mysterious girl who turns out to be an alien

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

Nearly 10 years ago, I watched a movie or short telefilm on TV. I have forgotten most of it, but I am providing highest detail possible based on my faint memory.

The story was based on a novel (as displayed in the intro or outro.... name not in my mind). It was floating around a cute blonde girl having age below 20 (my guess). She was new in town (filmed as small US town). She was a beautiful, kind, nice girl with a soft British accent. So, everyone liked her (including me outside TV).

She got some kid friends who started to be curious about her because very little was known about her... no family... nobody entering/exiting her home. One day, they invaded her home and got caught by a gorilla that just came with a bike. He was actually her family member (perhaps brother) in a gorilla suit. Kids got afraid at that time but increased their rate of invasion.

Time passed and society started to believe that she was alien (not seriously). I've forgotten what led to this conclusion. Anyway, she sensed it and started to socialize with society. Until the last scene, everyone thought that she was a normal human.

But, one day... she left everyone and was gone. I still remember that last scene: She was standing on a beach under a big saucer. She was weeping while surrounded by people. And, the saucer beamed her up and she was gone. She was really an alien!

The movie/telefilm title was something similar to this: {Name of girl} Was an Alien.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that must have been “[Sally Marshall Is Not an Alien](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0138771/)”.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sally_Marshall_Is_Not_an_Alien) has an extensive plot description, including the beach scene at the end you describe.

> Pip Lawson, a space-obsessed 12-year-old, makes a bet with a local bully, Rhonnie Bronston, to prove that the Marshalls, an oddball family moving into the neighborhood, are not aliens. With her telescope on the line, Pip befriends her new neighbor, Sally Marshall, and works to win the bet.
>
> As Sally becomes the new target for Rhonnie and her gang of friends, Pip quits the bet, still maintaining her original position. After reaffirming their friendship, Sally reveals that she and the rest of her family are, in fact, aliens. They leave Earth in a UFO as Pip watches on. The telescope is returned, and Pip becomes friends with the former bully and the other neighborhood children.

Answer (score 4):

The only movie I can find like that is Stepsister from Planet Weird. It was a disney movie and the girl was blonde I don't believe she had a British accent but she did talk in a strange way. I think I remember her dad wearing a Gorilla suit at one point. It was a Disney Channel movie and the alien body she had was a bubble so I believe there was some floating camera angles they did.

Comment: That wasn't necessarily a movie... I do have partial title in mind, so it wasn't "Stepsister from Planet Weird"..

Comment: I have just read quick story of "Stepsister from Planet Weird". Its 100% wrong identification. I've clearly mentioned in question that the girl was an alien... not normal human whose mother fell in love with an alien..

Comment: The stepsister is an alien. She has blonde hair. It was shown about ten years ago as a tv movie. So what do you mean by "That wasn't necessarily a movie.."

Comment: Yup.. maybe "TV Movie".. thanks for clarification.

Comment: I've just seen photos of that girl from movie. She's not who I'm looking for. But, in case, my graphical memory got tangled, can you please verify the last scene in question...

Comment: No the endings don't match up. I'll leave my answer up for now until you get another one so that the comments will show for others. Do you have any other information?