# 90/80s young adult sci-fi tv show: young girl turns out to be alien princess (or some such)

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm trying to find a tv-series/mini-series that I viewed as a teenager, probably in the 90s, possibly late 80s.

A pair of siblings (twins as I remembers) grow up in a nice neighbourhood. One day an old lady moves in next door. 
Soon after, at a birthday the sister gets roller skates and is accidentally hit by a car. When taken to the hospital the doctors find that she doesn't seem to be human (not the right number of organs or something like that).

I can't remember the exact story after that, but it turns out that sister is actually an alien while the brother is a normal human. The neighbour is an alien as well sent to protect the girl. They are at some point attacked by light sabre wielding aliens (looking like big red bears on two legs and made of energy).

As I remember it ends with most of the family (at least the brother and sister) leaving the earth and as the sister leaves she turns into her alien form (lots of white shining light).

I don't think it is US made, possibly Canadian, Australian or from the UK.

Comment: Is this the same as http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10115/4495 ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. The plot doesn't sound right and in my memory (granted, I was a lot younger at the time) the girl looked slightly older than Sally. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Was it animated? Live action?

Comment: Definitely Live Action. This was a while ago but as I remember it had quite good special effects too, if not very many.

Comment: Voted to reopen because one was about the movie, and the other was about the novel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I've found a match - a 1992 Australian TV movie called *The Distant Home*.  There's also a novel version (see [the description of the book at Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6481880-the-distant-home%20%22h)); it appears to be a novelization of the movie, rather than the source material for it, but I can't be sure.  See if this sounds familiar (it's the novel, not the movie, but it should be quite close if the movie came first):

> Sally and Jimmy are twins living with their parents in the most boring suburban street in the world but on their 12th birthday an accident and subsequent medical treatment reveal that Sally is an alien. Her twin brother Jimmy is human but she is not. For a thousand years a space war has been raging between a Galactic Empire and Ursoid invaders and Sally, an Imperial princess, was implanted in the womb of a human mother in order to hide her from her Ursoid enemies. The night the twins were born, an old lady named Mrs Webster moved into the house next door and ever since she has given the twins cookies, milk and lessons in military strategy. Now Sally’s secret is out, her Ursoid enemies are coming for her and the twins and Mrs Webster, now revealed as an undercover Master Sergeant in the Imperial Marines, tasked to be Sally’ bodyguard, have to keep her alive until help arrives from the Galactic Empire.