# Movie about a blue-blooded alien princess, sent to Earth for safekeeping

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

The movie was about a girl who seemed normal, she had a brother (I think they were twins but not sure). She gets sick or is injured and is taken to the hospital. They take blood from her and it turns out to be blue.

Eventually, it is revealed that she is an alien princess and was brought to Earth for safe keeping and is not related to her family. In the end, she leaves and goes back to her planet. It's kind of an old movie, from around the 90's.

Also, I think there was an elderly woman (might be her neighbour or grandmother), who was also an alien and was her protector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly *The Distant Home*, a 1992 Australian TV movie.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0284054/):

> Jim and Maria Harrison are an ordinary couple living in an ordinary suburb. The only extraordinary thing about them is that their daughter Sally is about to become ruler of the galaxy.
>
> The Harrisons were expecting their first child. On the way to the hospital the weather was strange, the electrical system of the family sedan failed, **and when their child is born, it was unexpectedly twins, a boy and a girl, Bobby and Sally.**
>
> What the Harrisons did not know was that the leader of the Galazy Empire was also pregnant at the time. **As there was a war between the Empire and the Confederacy, to safeguard the Empires child, it was implanted in Maria's womb and left up to her to raise.**
>
> Twelve years pass and the twins have grown up, but the time has come for Sally to return to her real family, and rule as she was meant to. **Unfortunately she is knocked over by a car while riding her new bike and is taken to hospital where it is discovered that she is an alien.** With the government involved, Sally is unable to return to either family until the Harrisons make plans to rescue her and return her to her real mother and fulfill her destiny out among the stars.

The movie is on YouTube (in Castilian Spanish).

---

Found by searching this site for `[story-identification] alien princess` which returned, among others, [Identification: 90/80s young adult sci-fi tv show. Young girl turns out to be alien princess (or some such)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/59399/)

Comment: Yep, that's the one. Thanks so much.

Comment: @FirstLast you're welcome, enjoy the rewatch :)